# SSIS - How do I fail a task if the data already exists in the DB

Tags: ssis

I'm new to SSIS so please bear with me.

I've a file that gets inserted to the database on a daily basis. I want to add a task that checks if the 'Source' and 'BatchNumber' already exists within a record in the database. If the task finds a 'Source' and 'BatchNumber' then it should fail the task and the package.

At the moment I have a lookup transformation that gets the 'Source' and 'BatchNumber' from the flat file  and the 'Source' and 'BatchNumber' from the table in the DB. Despite experimenting and researching I'm stuck at how to proceed further.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a lot of info to go on! Have you tried a Conditional Split Transform? This will direct the output in one or more flows depending on the conditions you enter. This is assuming you are trying to work out how to direct the flow.......

[Conditional Split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UWYc.png)

[Conditional Split 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfdK9.png)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. A conditional split isn't going to help unless one *already* knows that something is a duplicate. Perhaps this should be a comment instead of an answer ?